# TinyMCE not giving me bullist or numlist icons in menu

Tags: tinymce

I have a page with multiple textarea's that I am converting to tinymce fields.

```
<script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.input-textarea',
        toolbar: 'bold italic | bullist numlist indent outdent',
        statusbar: false,
        menubar: false,
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        contextmenu: false
    });
</script>
```

The textareas are all class input-textarea, and the tinymce editor is loading jsut fine.  Except, for some reason all the menu buttons are showing except the bullist and the numlist.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to load the `lists` plugin to use those toolbar buttons:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
  ],
  toolbar: "bullist numlist"
});
```

There is also an `advlist` plugin with additional features that you may be interested in using:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/advlist/

Comment: So I add the plugins and it works, but I am trying to limit functionality to fit within style requirements.  If I remove the advlists plugin to remove the options dropdown the list buttons go away entirely.  Do I have to include advlists to get lists?  And was this a recent change? 2 weeks ago bullists and numlists were showing without the plugin fields.

Comment: I don't need to use `advlists` just to get the button to show - but I do need `lists`:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/MDfaab

Comment: I have checked the same answer in may forums, but I could not solve my problem even I have tested both lists and advlist plugins